# How to regenerate menu items properly after first usage of ItemContainerGenerator?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have simple xaml code - Menu with single item that contains binded itemsCollection:

```
<Menu x:Name="Menu" Focusable="False">
        <MenuItem DataContext="{Binding Menu.RootItem}" SubmenuOpened="MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Menu, Path=DataContext.Menu.Items}" >
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

In order to focus first menu item I tried the common approach at *MenuItem_OnSubmenuOpened*:

```
var root = ((MenuItem) sender);
        var items = root.Items;
        //tried this one without any success to regenerate UI Children
        root.UpdateLayout();

        if (items.Count > 0) {
            if (root.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) {
                ShowItems(root);
            }
            else {
                EventHandler itemsGenerated = null;
                itemsGenerated = delegate {
                    if (root.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated) {
                        root.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= itemsGenerated;
                        ShowItems(root);
                    }
                };
                root.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += itemsGenerated;
            }
        }
```

And helper method where *Focus()* invoked;

```
private void ShowItems(MenuItem root) {
        ((MenuItem) root.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(root.Items[0])).Focus();
    }
```

**It works fine for the first time.** But after that when I invoke *Focus()* nothing happend, and *Focus()* returns false. Tried to loop it, but without any success because item is unreachable. There is no Virtualization and I tried to disable it explicitly with *VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing* but still the same. Tried to *UpdateLayout* in order to update *ItemContainerGenerator* but still nothing changed. And I tried to use *ContainerFromIndex* too though this is really minor change without actual difference.
How to regenerate menu items properly after first usage of ItemContainerGenerator?